# Confluent Schema Registry - why is auto.register.schemas not applicable at schema-registry level, instead at the producer level

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

i've installed the Schema Registry and want to set the auto.register.schema set to false - so only avro messages conforming to the registered schema can be published to Kafka Topic.

From whet i understand, the property - auto.register.schemas is a Kafka Producer property, and not a schema registry property.

Here is the code I use to set the property auto.register.schemas

```
Console Producer:

kafka-avro-console-producer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 --topic srtest-optionalfield --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f2","type":"string"}]}' --property value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy --property auto.register.schemas=false


Java Avro Producer : 

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "http://localhost:9092");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "Kafka Avro  Producer");
props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, false);
```

Does this mean that - if a Kafka producer passes the property auto.register.schemas=true, it will be able to add the schema to the Schema Registry.

This does not provide safeguard, since I want to ensure that producer is allowed to produce only messages that conform to schemas in Schema Registry

How do I do this ?
Is there a way from me to set the property - auto.register.schemas - at the Schema Registry level ?

tia!